# Escaping Puppet manifest variables in Jenkins job

Tags: jenkins, syntax-error, puppet

I am getting syntax errors thrown around some variables used in my Puppet manifest on a Jenkins "Execute Shell" build step.  When I do:

```
hostname => \$node1,
```

...this works fine.  However, when I do a hash like this:

```
hostnames => { \$node1 => \$node1_priv, \$node2 => \$node2_priv },
```

... I get a `Syntax error at 'node1'; expected '}' at...`.

I've tried using the syntax `\${node1}`, and even `"\$node"` but neither are working.

EDIT!
Variables are declared like:

```
\$node1 = 'host1'
\$node2 = 'host2'
class {'classname':
   ...
```

Comment: Can we get a little more context for those expressions? - Generally, using unquoted strings in hashes is discouraged. How about `hostnames => { '$node1' => '$node1_priv', ... }` ?

Comment: @FelixFrank I have updated my question with a couple of examples.  The values are enclosed in single quotes.

Comment: Wait, so you **have** a variabe `$node1` etc. that you want Puppet to expand? Why would you escape the dollar sign? `hostnames => { $node1 => $node1_priv }`

Comment: Because its used within an Execute Shell job in Jenkins.  The manifest is built up like `/bin/cat > $WORKSPACE/mih_manifest.pp <<EOF`, then a `puppet apply` is run with the manifest.

Comment: So what you are posting is not manifest code but what, bash? Which eventually ends up in a manifest. Can you please rework your question so that it relates the whole context, i.e. (1) the script that generates the manifest and (b) the resulting manifest. As it is, your problem is utterly unparseable.